# How to refactor this piece of code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, ruby-2.0

I'm new to ruby on rails, on this project I'm using ruby 2.0 and rails 3.0

I would like to know if this piece of code can be refactored, as it is

```
unless params["ot_code"].nil?       
    ots = params["ot_code"].gsub(/\r\n?/, "").gsub(";","','").upcase
    ots[ots.length,1] = "'"
    ots =  ots.rjust(ots.length+1,"'")
end

unless params["circuit_id_multiple"].nil?
    multiple_circuit = params["circuit_id_multiple"].gsub(/\r\n?/, "").gsub(";","','")
    multiple_circuit[multiple_circuit.length,1] = "'"
    multiple_circuit = multiple_circuit.rjust(multiple_circuit.length+1,"'")
end

unless params["multiple_element_code"].nil?
    multiple_element_code = params["multiple_element_code"].gsub(/\r\n?/, "").gsub(";","','")
    multiple_element_code[multiple_element_code.length,1] = "'"
    multiple_element_code = multiple_element_code.rjust(multiple_element_code.length+1,"'")
end
```

Comment: I think you should post it here : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `unless params["ot_code"].nil?` => `if params["ot_code"]`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code-review and should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

1. **Don't use no double negatives**

   Rails parameters are either strings or `nil`. So instead of:

   ```
   unless params["ot_code"].nil?
   ```

   Just write:

   ```
   if params["ot_code"]
   ```
2. **Keep it simple**

   I suppose this should wrap a string in single quotes:

   ```
   ots[ots.length,1] = "'"
   ots = ots.rjust(ots.length+1,"'")
   ```

   You can instead simply write:

   ```
   ots = "'#{ots}'"
   ```
3. **Don't repeat yourself**

   You are repeating the same processing steps 3 times. Write a method instead:

   ```
   def convert(str)
     str = str.gsub(/\r\n?/, "")  # remove newlines
     str = str.gsub(";", "','")   # convert semicolons
     "'#{str}'"                   # wrap in single quotes
   end

   def action_method
     ots = convert(params["ot_code"]).upcase if params["ot_code"]
     multiple_circuit = convert(params["circuit_id_multiple"]) if params["circuit_id_multiple"]
     multiple_element_code = convert(params["multiple_element_code"]) if params["multiple_element_code"]
   end
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `unless params["ot_code"].nil?` isn't the same as `if params["ot_code"]`. The first tests for `nil` and the second could fail if it was `false` and not `nil`.

Comment: That's right, but in this context (Rails), it's a string or `nil`.